# command gem install rails fails with permissions error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to install a gem (gem install rails) fails with this error:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
Anyone having idea how to solve this?

i am trying to installing rails from unix.

Answer (score -1):

> [Sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudo.man.html) command allows you to execute a command as a superuser

So the following command should work with you.

```
sudo gem install rails
```